# login with facebook connect

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to add facebook oauth to my website. The "login with facebook" button hits the following URL

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=292861684087978&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/foobar/register/facebookLoginHandler&scope=user_about_me,email

When the button is clicked I get the error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

So it seems like facebook doesn't like my `redirect_uri`. I've registered my app with the following settings on facebook:

```
App Domain: foobar.ie
Site URL: http://www.foobar.ie
```

Obviously while I'm testing locally, the `redirect_uri` doesn't correspond to my registered domain, but my understanding is that facebook always allows `localhost:8080` for the purpose of testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent managed to get it working with localhost URLS.  What I do is add an entry in my hosts file and then give facebook the mapped url.
You wont be able to use the [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) for testing Open Graph stuff, but you'll be able to view the canvas of your app - apps.facebook.com/your_app for testing purposes as the canvas apps are run in an iFrame and calls to it originate from the client machine therefore going through the hosts file.  You'll have to update every (tester's) computer's hosts file for them to be able to view your locally developed app.